# 'list' object is not callable for find same elements in two different list

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new in Python, I don't know where I made mistakes

```
def q(listA, listB):

    list1=[]
    for a in range(len(listA)):
        for b in range(len(listB)):
            if listA(a)==listB(b):
                list1.append(a)
    list2=[]
    for x in range(len(listb)):
        for y in range(len(listA)):
            if listB(x)==listA(y):
                list2.append(x)
    
    
    return list(zip(list1,list2))

pairAPy = [1,2,3,4]
pairBPy = [1,5,7,2]
print(q(pairAPy,pairBPy))
```

```
Line 21 print(q(pairAPy,pairBPy))  
 Line 8             if listA(a)==listB(b):  
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

and the answer should return `[(0, 0), (2, 1), (3, 3)]`.

Comment: You want `if listA[a] == listB[b]`

Comment: `if listA[a]==listB[b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally used `(a)` and `(b)` instead of `[a]` and `[b]`. Your code should look like this:

```py
def q(listA, listB):

    list1 = []
    for a in range(len(listA)):
        for b in range(len(listB)):
            **if listA[a] == listB[b]:
                list1.append(a)
    list2=[]
    for x in range(len(listb)):
        for y in range(len(listA)):
            if listB[x] == listA[y]:
                list2.append(x)
    
    
    return list(zip(list1, list2))

pairAPy = [1,2,3,4]
pairBPy = [1,5,7,2]
print(q(pairAPy, pairBPy))
```